# No implementation found for Native Lcom/slytechs/library/NativeLibrary

Tags: java, android, native-code, jnetpcap

I am stack in using JNetPcap library in an Android project: 
I can't reach my native application with this code, even I set up the JNetPcap as a library for the project.

Could someone help me ? plz

My code is as below :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;

import org.jnetpcap.PcapIf;
import org.jnetpcap.packet.JMemoryPacket;
import org.jnetpcap.packet.JPacket;
import org.jnetpcap.protocol.JProtocol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Server_Android extends Activity{

    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 1234;
//    public final static int RECEIVING_TIMEOUT_SERVER = 3000;
    DatagramSocket socket;
    DatagramPacket packetOut;
    DatagramPacket packetIn;
    byte[] DataIn;
    byte[] DataOut;
    List<PcapIf> alldevs;
    StringBuilder errbuf;

    /*Android widgets*/
    TextView text;
    EditText edit;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_android);
        //text = (EditText)
        button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);   
        text.setText("");

        handlingpacket();

        /* Thread for receiving Data from CLient */
        new Thread(new Message_handler()).start();
            try {   
        Thread.sleep(500);
        reply();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Log.e("UDP", "UDP receive failed!");
        }

    }

//  
    public void handlingpacket(){

        JPacket jmp = new JMemoryPacket(JProtocol.UDP_ID,
                  "001801bf 6adc0025 4bb7afec 08004500 "  
                + " 0041a983 40004006 d69ac0a8 00342f8c "  
                + " ca30c3ef 008f2e80 11f52ea8 4b578018 "  
                + " ffffa6ea 00000101 080a152e ef03002a "  
                + " 2c943538 322e3430 204e4f4f 500d0a");
        text.append("" + jmp);

    }
//  
    public class Message_handler implements Runnable{

            public Message_handler(){}

            public void run(){

            try {
                DataOut = new byte[1024];

            while(true){

                    socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                    socket.setBroadcast(true);
        //          socket.setSoTimeout(RECEIVING_TIMEOUT_SERVER);
                    packetIn = new DatagramPacket(DataOut,DataOut.length);          
                    socket.receive(packetIn);

                        runOnUiThread( new Runnable(){ // original thread for UI interactions

                                public void run(){
                                    String message = new String(packetIn.getData());
                                    text.append("Message " + message +"\n From :" + packetIn.getAddress() + " on port : "+  packetIn.getPort() +"\n");
                                    Log.d("UDP", "le message reçu");
                                    Log.d("Message : ", "" + message);  

                                }
                        });


                }
            }
                catch(UnknownHostException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(SocketException exc) {
                    System.out.println("Problem openning socket");
                }
                catch(IOException exc) {
                    System.out.println("Problem in reception of messages");
                }

            socket.close();

            }

        }

        public void reply(){

            DataIn = new byte[1024];
            button.setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener(){    

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {

                        socket = new DatagramSocket(); 
                        String str = edit.getText().toString();
                        DataIn = str.getBytes();
                        packetOut = new DatagramPacket(DataIn, DataIn.length, packetIn.getAddress(), packetIn.getPort());
                        socket.send(packetOut);
                        }catch (SocketException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }   
                         catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
}
```

The Log file:

```
08-21 11:18:36.755: W/dalvikvm(776): No implementation found for native Lcom/slytechs/library/NativeLibrary;.dlopen (Ljava/lang/String;)J
08-21 11:18:36.755: W/dalvikvm(776): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/jnetpcap/nio/JMemory;
08-21 11:18:36.755: D/AndroidRuntime(776): Shutting down VM
08-21 11:18:36.755: W/dalvikvm(776): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a2d1f8)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.example.server_android.Server_Android.handlingpacket(Server_Android.java:66)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.example.server_android.Server_Android.onCreate(Server_Android.java:50)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Native Method)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at org.jnetpcap.nio.JMemory.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
08-21 11:18:36.760: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  ... 16 more
```

Comment: `JMemoryPacket` is creating exception. it may be not found or unknown source for your code.

Comment: yes sure but how to make it known for the Java project?

Answer (score 0):

I just corrected this issue in my application.

If you are running this from an IDE make sure that your DLL and the IDE are both 32bit or 64bit.

Otherwise, put the the DLL in the same folder from which you will execute your jar or specify the location using -Djava.library.path.

Comment: No.  This has nothing to do with a DLL, as it is a runtime error on an Android system, and as Android is not windows it does not use the DLL library format, but rather it's own variation of the Linux .so format.